# I configured sonar in my local host Ubuntu 16.04 but http://localhost:9000/sonar not working

Tags: apache, sonarqube

I am configuring sonar(https://www.sonarqube.org) to my local machine which has Ubuntu 16.04 OS with LAMP(Linux,Apache,mysql,PHP) installed in it.

I have considered these reference link to setup SonarPHP
https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-sonarqube-on-ubuntu-1604/
https://www.talentica.com/blogs/sonarqube-php-project-ubuntu/

Now I can see that sonar is running in my PC but link http://localhost:9000/sonar is not working.

Please help me.

Comment: Did you try  http://localhost:9000 ?

Comment: yes . I tried that but it's not working.

Comment: Have a look at the log files. Did you check the r/w rights of the folder you have installed the software?

Comment: @JeroenHeier yes I checked that.

Comment: Can you also clarify `not working`: what are you getting when you try and connect? A 'connection refused', '404 Not Found', 'Internal Server Error', something else?

Comment: I downloaded "Community Edition 7.7" rather than "Developer Edition 7.7" it's working now.

Answer (score 1):

After lot of research I found the solution. I am explaining step by step process of how to setup Sonar in Ubuntu16.04 so other's developer who is new to sonar can understand this process.

**Step 1**

Download sonar "Community Edition 7.7" from this link https://www.sonarqube.org/downloads/

**Step 2**

Unzip file and move folder to `/opt/sonarqube`

**Step 3**

Update Sonar configuration file

```
sudo vi sonarqube-7.0/conf/sonar.properties
```

Update following values [database user = sonarqube,database = sonarqube]

```
sonar.jdbc.username=sonarqube
sonar.jdbc.password=some_secure_password

sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonarqube?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance&useSSL=false

sonar.web.host=127.0.0.1
sonar.web.javaAdditionalOpts=-server

...
```

**Step 4**

Create new service in ubuntu 16.04

```
sudo vi /etc/systemd/system/sonarqube.service
```

add following text to file and make sure that you have double checked mentioned path.

```
[Unit]
Description=SonarQube service
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking

ExecStart=/opt/sonarqube/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh start
ExecStop=/opt/sonarqube/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh stop

User=sonarqube
Group=sonarqube
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Start sonar by following command

```
sudo service sonarqube start
```

Check sonar status using following command

```
service sonarqube status
```

Enable sonar by following command

```
sudo systemctl enable sonarqube
```

**Step 5**

Create Mysql database user and database with following details

Database Username : sonarqube

Database Name : sonarqube

Done.

For project scan you have to download and setup sonar-scanner.

I have taken following links for reference.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-ensure-code-quality-with-sonarqube-on-ubuntu-16-04

https://www.talentica.com/blogs/sonarqube-php-project-ubuntu/